# copy data frame to the other matching row number

Tags: r

I have a dataframe A like below. 
Notice that the first column is the row name with random order.

```
   ID
5  10
3  10
1  10
```

Them. I have another 5 * 1 data frame B with NAs. I am trying to copy A to B matching the column names in A. I want to get a data frame like below.

```
   ID
1  10
2  NA
3  10
4  NA
5  10
```

Comment: Just do `B$ID[row.names(A)] <- A$ID`

Comment: Does `B` have a different column name? Or are there multiple columns in `B`? Is `B` guaranteed to have all the row names from A? You say "matching the column names in A", does that  mean `A` actually has multiple columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is potentially dangerous. If you are 100% sure that the rows contain identifiers that would match between the 2 data frames, here's the code.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate a data frame that looks like yours (you don't need this)
df <- data.frame(ID=c(10, NA, 10, NA, 10))

# Assign row names to a new column on the df
df$names <- row.names(df)
# Here's how your data will look like
df<-df[complete.cases(df),]

# Make a second df
df2 <- data.frame(names=as.character(1:20))
# Join by names (what are other possible columns to join by ?)
left_join(df2, df, by="names")
```

This will produce

```
   names ID
1      1 10
2      2 NA
3      3 10
4      4 NA
5      5 10
6      6 NA
7      7 NA
8      8 NA
9      9 NA
10    10 NA
11    11 NA
12    12 NA
13    13 NA
14    14 NA
15    15 NA
16    16 NA
17    17 NA
18    18 NA
19    19 NA
20    20 NA
```